# Is there a way to apply a CSS file to a particular div?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with a header, a navigation pane on the left, and a **content** pane on the right.  The content pane is a pure white background, and I would like to apply an entirely different set of styles to it than the other two panes.

Is there a way to apply a style sheet to the div of the content pane, without having to resort to putting `#content` in front of each and every one of my css classes in the "content" css file?  Or is putting `#content` in front of each class the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting #content in front is the right way.

The only way to apply a whole stylesheet to a single element without using selectors would be to put it into an IFrame, which would cause a heap of other problems.

Comment: That's too bad.  It means the style sheet can't be genericized; i.e. I would have to strip #content from the sheet to use it anywhere else.

Comment: Class selectors are the way to go to generalize rules.To be able to use everything you need in every place is a question of clever planning - I find that sometimes harder than it looks at first sight.
I had a similar question a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731555/reset-css-for-a-certain-area-of-the-page

Comment: I like the *idea* of a reset css, but **yikes.** It's the nuclear option. I think I'll go with the #content selectors. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: The reset CSS may be daunting initially, but as you use it you realize you're no longer dealing with a lot of the "IE has 3 extra pixels here" issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little wacky, but if your page is dynamic, you could inject a compressed stylesheet directly into the style attribute of the element.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I hadn't thought of that.  If I were building a full-blown CMS, I might consider that.

Comment: Wacky and interesting idea. +1