# unreset the reset css

Tags: css, reset

I am using reset css for my application which includes ck editor, i dont want the reset css should be applied for the output of CK editor inside my html page. How to unset the reset css for the particular portion of a page?

Comment: The short answer is you can't.

Comment: Heh, seems I had the same problem once! Duplicate of  [Reset CSS for a certain area of the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731555/reset-css-for-a-certain-area-of-the-page)

Comment: why would you want that anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Give the CK output a class.  Write your own CSS code after the reset.css code.  Refer to the class and give it the properties that you prefer.  For example:

index.html:

```
<p>Normal text formatted by reset.css</p>
<span class="my-format"><p>Output of CK editor to be formatted by my CSS</p></span>
```

style.css:

```
@import url("reset.css");
/* My code goes down here: */
.my-format { font: normal 14px georgia,times,serif; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You havent quite understood the point of a reset.css, have you?

You cannot apply some CSS to make all browsers read the css differently (like the do before, like padding, margin, lineheight, zoom and other things)